# How can I use module file in the document ready funciton

Tags: javascript, npm

There is a config module file contained some enviorment paramters, I want to call it in the document ready function. Because the document ready function is firstly called, it will throw undefined error.The config file has been already used in other module files. Could someone make any suggestions here? Thanks

```
kconfig.js

    const kconfig = (function () {
    function kconfig() {

    }

    kconfig.webApiUrl = "http://localhost/webapi/"

    return kconfig;
})()

export default kconfig;
```

index.html page

```
    <script type="module" src="../../config/kconfig.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            console.log('document ready...')
            console.log(kconfig.webApiUrl)
            //$.ajaxGet(kconfig.webApiUrl + 'api/hello/query/123')
        });
    </script>
```

error detail:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: kconfig is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you requiring kconfig and then also importing it? import is just the es6 implementation of require. You should just be doing import kconfig from '../../config/kconfig'; and not the line after it. Also, you're not importing kconfig in the script that it's used in, that may cause a problem although I dont think it would because the first script tag should be executed first and then be accessible globally. Hope this points you in a helpful direction.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to import kconfig file directly. But it's still throws an undefined error. The module file isn't loaded until document ready. I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: You cant just put the file in the src property because you have to set kconfig equal to something (or name it as the value of an import like in import kconfig from ...). You're using kconfig but you dont define what it is anywhere

Comment: Try doing import kconfig from '../../config/kconfig; window.kconfig = kconfig; and then anytime you want to use kconfig use window.kconfig